# Where are my VisualForce Bar Chart's Bar's?

Tags: visualforce, soql, apex, charts, visualforce-charting

Currently looking at [Providing Chart Data via a Controller Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_providing_data_controller_method.htm).

Something seems to be either missing or failing, as the bar chart is being displayed *WITHOUT* the bars:

[image]

Here is my VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="VF_OpportunityVFCtrl">
<apex:chart data="{!opportunityList}" width="600" height="400">
     <apex:axis type="Category" position="left"   fields="Name"   title="Opportunities"/>
     <apex:axis type="Numeric"  position="bottom" fields="Amount" title="Amount"/>
     <apex:barSeries orientation="horizontal" axis="bottom" xField="Name" yField="Amount"/>
</apex:chart>
<apex:dataTable value="{!opportunityList}" var="opportunity">
    <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity" value="{!opportunity.name}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Amount"      value="{!opportunity.amount}"/>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Here is my controller:

```
  public class VF_OpportunityVFCtrl 
{
    // Get a set of Opportunities
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController
    {
        get
        {
            if (standardSetController == null)
            {
                standardSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(VF_OpportunityDao.getQueryLocator());
                standardSetController.setPageSize(5);
            }
            return standardSetController;
        }
        set;
    }   

    public List<Opportunity> getOpportunityList()
    {
        return (List<Opportunity>) standardSetController.getRecords();
    }
}
```

And here is the Dao class:

```
    public class VF_OpportunityDao 
{
    public static Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator()
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
                                            SELECT name, type, amount, closeDate
                                            FROM Opportunity
                                       ]);
    }
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: I had the same and it was caused by a conflict with bootstrap styling. Is the page on it's own or is any additional styling applied?

Comment: @guy, Completely on its own.  Only styling comes from SFDC.  (All code is above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<apex:barSeries orientation="horizontal" axis="bottom" xField="Name" yField="Amount"/>
```

to:

```
<apex:barSeries orientation="horizontal" axis="bottom" xField="Amount" yField="Name"/>
```

as the numeric axis is the x axis. (With the wrong data types the chart data just isn't drawn.)

Comment: @BrianKessler Yeah I think some of the documentation has the same problem - I've seen the problem before.